# Replace an image with its alt-tag

Tags: php, html

Hoi,

i have a string filled with html-content. What i need to do now is, to replace every image with its alt-text.

The html can look like this:

```
<h1> some h1</h1>

<img src="images/image.jpg" alt="My Alt-text" width="540" height="304" />
<img src="images_2003/basket.jpg" alt="My other alt text" width="540" height="304" />

<h2>some h2</h2>

<img src="images/image2.jpg" alt="My next Alt-text" width="540" height="304" />
<img src="images/image45.jpg" alt="Yet other alt text" width="540" height="304" />

...
```

What it should be:

```
<h1> some h1</h1>

My Alt-text
My other alt text

<h2>some h2</h2>

My next Alt-text
Yet other alt text

...
```

What would be the best way, to accomplish this?

Comment: use [PHP DOM](http://php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php) if you've valid html

Comment: by using what Javascript, php..?

Comment: A primitive version could be `preg_replace('#<img.*alt="([^"]+)".*>#', '$1', $code);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a [DOM parser](https://www.php.net/domdocument) this is pretty straightforward:

```
$contents = <<<EOS
<h1> some h1</h1>

<img src="images/image.jpg" alt="My Alt-text" width="540" height="304" />
<img src="images_2003/basket.jpg" alt="My other alt text" width="540" height="304" />

<h2>some h2</h2>

<img src="images/image2.jpg" alt="My next Alt-text" width="540" height="304" />
<img src="images/image45.jpg" alt="Yet other alt text" width="540" height="304" />
EOS;

$doc = new DOMDocument;
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$doc->loadHTML($contents);
libxml_clear_errors();

$xp = new DOMXPath($doc);
foreach ($xp->query('//img') as $node) {
        $text = $doc->createTextNode($node->getAttribute('alt') . "\n");
        $node->parentNode->replaceChild($text, $node);
}

echo $doc->saveHTML();
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use jquery to perform this operation.

Maybe try this code (I don't have test it) :

```
$("img").each(function() {
    var alt_txt = $(this).attr('alt');
    $(this).replaceWith(alt_txt);
});
```

Hope this helps ! Bye !

Answer (score 1):

If you need a jQuery solution try this

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var alt = ""
    $( "img" ).each(function( index ) {
      alt = $(this).attr("alt");
      $(this).replaceWith("<p>" + alt + "</p>");  // modify p with someother tag if needed.
    });
});
```

Play [here](http://jsfiddle.net/gR8uz/)